# How can I remove items on a table in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with XEDITABLE pluggin, but when I remove an item, this item doesn't remove, it removes another item. 
My code:

```
 vm.removeUser = function(index){
            console.log("entra");
            vm.datos.splice(index,1);
            console.log(index);
            refresh();
        };
```

Please help.

Comment: could you create a codepen http://codepen.io or plnkr http://plnkr.co and replicate your issue there.  also what is the index number that is logging in console is it the next records index than the one selected ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the array is filtered and/or ordered by the template when being displayed, which means that the indices in the view don't match with the indices of the original, unfiltered array in the model.

The solution is simple: don't pass the index as argument. Pass the object to remove itself:

```
vm.removeUser = function(userToRemove){
    vm.datos.splice(vm.datos.indexOf(userToRemove), 1);
};
```